# Using ngrok with SendGrid API Test POST / 404 Not Found -Works With Webhook.site

Tags: webhooks, sendgrid, ngrok, sendgrid-api-v3

I've setup webhooks in the SendGrid API and successfully tested it with webhook.site https://webhook.site/#!/97fcfe09-4481-45d0-94b1-df7cbf223ce0/b718bf1f-b48a-49bc-af9a-3345b4d6f6ea/1.

I am trying to configure it to work with a glitch node.js environment so I also successfully installed ngrok there:

```
Session Status                online                                                                                                            
Session Expires               1 hour, 53 minutes                                                                                                
Version                       2.3.40                                                                                                            
Region                        United States (us)                                                                                                
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                                                                                             
Forwarding                    http://dff1-35-175-191-91.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:3000                                                       
Forwarding                    https://dff1-35-175-191-91.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:3000                                                      
                                                                                                                                                
Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90                                                                       
                              1       0       0.00    0.00    5.01    5.01   

but when I try to replace the webhook.site url with http://dff1-35-175-191-91.ngrok.io I get an error in terminal  POST / 404 Not Found.

Any advice thanks.


I expected it to work and tried multiple ngrok generated urls
```

Answer (score 0):

think I figured it out I setup a webhook path in my glitch ide

/webhook

then using the glitch project url/webhook not the actual one suggested to test with ngrok